# Its possible to use a microsoft.web.services3 in visual studio database project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, wsdl, windows-services, database-project

I have done a windows service that gets information from an wsdl class method. A co-worker has suggested me to use an assembly to run a job in sqlserver database. I supossed it wasn't possible but i dont know if it could be done.

The wsdl that i'm using was done with Microsoft.web.services3. The windows service project has a config file which has a necessary section:

```
<configSections>
     <section name="microsoft.web.services3" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Configuration.WebServicesConfiguration, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</configSections>
```

And i also have this reference.

```
<microsoft.web.services3>
    <tokenIssuer>
       <ttlInSeconds value="900000" />
    </tokenIssuer>
    <security>
       <defaultTtlInSeconds value="9000000" />
      <timeToleranceInSeconds value="9000000" />
    </security>
<web.services3>
```

I think it won't work but if it could be possible, how can i do this in a Database Project to build in one assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but it is not really "nice" to do.
What you need to do is to create a SQL Server CLR Assembly where you use the Webservice logic (calling, handling, etc).

Look at [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.100).aspx] on how to do that

Downside to this, you are running this CLR in the SQL Server memory. If you don't dispose your objects in the proper way you might fill up your SQL Server memory with objects that are not meant to be there.

**Other solution?** 
If you need this data in a database, you might want to create a process that calls the webservice and stores the data in a database...

Comment: I will try the first  solution and also i will notify you if it works. Thank you

Comment: Hi Mark, I did it yesterday but i encountered a new a problem. When my backend co-worker was adding assembly we got a lot of errors by  others .dll dependency. I possible to get all the dependencies in the same .dll? The project has some .dll dependency like epplus, razor, mvc, services3...

Comment: I am not sure why you want all those Front End assemblies within your webservice? Make sure that the webservice is only doing what it is supposed to do. A webservice shouldn't have to do anything with razor/mvc. Maybe you want to call the service from the frontend, but it should not be included... Go back to the design of your objects/classes and make sure everything is non-dependant

Comment: We have some common libraries we use to export excel, another web utils... each has the own references. When i'm adding reference to use the serializer class, its project has those references and when we try to add the dll in backend it crashes because of it is unable to get those references. I dont know if understand me, sorry for my bad english.